# Install TortoiseHg for mac : No module named mercurial

Tags: python, mercurial, python-2.7, tortoisehg

I'm trying to install TortoiseHg for Mac following these instructions : https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/developers/MacOSX#!alternative-install-via-macports

I'm trying to follow the instructions about the "Alternative: Install via Homebrew" and I have an issue.

When I execute `./thg log` as in the instructions it works, TortoiseHg is launching. However when I try to create an App from the python script, the App is created but when I launch it it crashes.

Here is the output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabienhenon/Documents/thg-mac-app/dist/TortoiseHg.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 316, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/fabienhenon/Documents/thg-mac-app/dist/TortoiseHg.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 311, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/fabienhenon/Documents/thg-mac-app/dist/TortoiseHg.app/Contents/Resources/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    imp.load_source("thg", SCRIPT_DIR + "/bin/thg")
  File "/Users/fabienhenon/Documents/thg-mac-app/dist/TortoiseHg.app/Contents/Resources/bin/thg", line 56, in <module>
    from mercurial import demandimport
ImportError: No module named mercurial
2013-01-06 12:25:17.436 TortoiseHg[406:707] TortoiseHg Error
logout

[Opération terminée]
```

When I type : `hg --version` I have the following output :

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.4.2+20130102)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2012 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Can somebody help me with this issue ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: If you want it for mercurial, I advise you to use SourceTree, I use it and I am very happy with it.

Comment: @ipinak I used SourceTree on another Mac but it was creating a corruption in the repository each time I pushed something. Hpefully I had access to this repository and I could repair it but now it's for a repository hosts on bitbucket and I'm afraid to get the same error :( That's why I'm trying to get TortoiseHg on mac

Comment: @FabienHenon I don't have an answer, but if one is found, it would also be useful to me.  I use TortoiseHg on Mac.  I tried to get it working as an app, but wasn't able to get it working.  Instead, I just run it from the command-line.

Comment: I think it's ridiculous that there's no simple package for TortoiseHg on the Mac. All the Mac alternatives suck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution to solve this issue.

From the error message I had, the script could not find the module named mercurial. I'm new with Python so I had to make some researches to know how module importation works and I found something about dynamically importing a module using the `'sys'` module.

My solution was to edit the tortoisehg source code (the file where the error came from) to dynamically add the path to my mercurial module to the `'sys.path'` so that the program knows where to find the mercurial module.

Here is the code (in the 'thg' python file, line 56 (as mentioned by the error)) :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages")
```

You have to add this code just before this line :

```
from mercurial import demandimport
```

And the path must correspond to the location of your mercurial folder.